# typeahead function prevent editbox styling

Tags: xpages, type-ahead

I have two edit boxes on my xPage.
Second one with typeahead enabled.
I want on onFocus event make editbox background e.g. yellow...
I do it this way:

```
var fldObj = dojo.byId("myEditBox");
if (!fldObj) {
    fldObj = dojo.query("[id$=':myEditBox']");
    if (fldObj) {
        fldObj = fldObj[0];
    }
}
if (fldObj != null) {
    fldObj.style.background="yellow";
}
```

it works perfect for the first edit box but not for the one with typeahead enabled..
Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: What are the IDs of the edit boxes? Please add more code from your XPage.

Comment: ID is myEditBox... 
as I said it works fine for first editBox but not for second one that has only typeAhead enabled

Comment: Your code is just changing the first element found (*fldObj = fldObj[0];*) If you have two elements, the second one is never touched.

Comment: Again, as I said it works fine without typeAhead enabled... Sorry If I confuse you - it's xPage project

Comment: I have no  crystal ball. The code works fine on a test page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple CSS does the trick. Your problem is probably caused by dojo CSS styling. Added !important overrides other inherited !important styling. Works for me with edit box with and without typeahead.

```
.xspInputFieldEditBox:focus, .lotusui .dijitTextBox input:focus, .xspComboBox:focus
{
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: yellow !important;
  background: yellow !important;

}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp

Comment: Tested in oneUI application.

Comment: I'm very sorry Frantisek to trouble you again.. How to do same for dijitCombobox..  I tried .xspInputText:focus, .lotusui .dijitComboBox input:focus with no success... Thank you

Comment: As Frantisek said, you should ACCEPT the answer. Important part of participating in stackoverflow